# Index access operator weird syntax

Tags: typescript

Consider this code that results in a TS compiler error:

```
interface Car {
  manufacturer: string;
  model: string;
}

let taxi: Car = {
  manufacturer: 'Toyota',
  model: 'Camry',
};

// this code returns an error. why??
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, propertyName: K): K {
  return o[propertyName];
}

let makeAndModel: string[] = getProperty(taxi, 'model');
```

`T` is an arbitrary type, and `K extends keyof T` (i.e. K must be one of the `T` keys, in our case it can be `manufacturer` or `model`). In the function return type we declare `K` as our return type, so we already tell to the compiler: "Hey, this function can only return variable of type (`K`) that must be one of the taxi (`T`) keys (`manufacturer`, `model`).

That's it. That's all that the compiler should know. We have already limited `K` to be one the `T` keys. Why then we need to surround `K` with additional `[]` right here:

```
// this code works. why??
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, propertyName: K): [K] { // additional []. any reason?
  return o[propertyName];
}
```

Comment: Let the types flow. TypeScript is about having types, not using then in every possible position and thereby frustrating type inference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type is wrong. You're returning value, not a key, so it should be:

```
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, propertyName: K): T[K] {
    return o[propertyName];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gKGcgWzhAFd4EwSpoAuZAZzClAHMBuPQgewBMIAbOo2Yh2OAL44c-CGGRg4AD2B10mALzZORUuUrUodAOQAVLgE8uCowBptvAcfQEo52xI44YJEBWBcQZBZZAAUoLgAHaDBzAB4TG2QAaWQIRUgQHnpkAGsISxhkEwA%20AAouOgTkCPCoqBiAOTgCCDokgEpKgG0kgF0tfHxqfUCuLprI6PMmlt6OSWlZbj5%20ZE1gsDDJ%20vNShWVEowIHfiN2tiA)